# How to throttle a method by concurrent invocations in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to use any `Spring` library to "throttle" the number of concurrent invocations of a method? Like:

```
@RestController
public class MyRest {
   @RequestMethod
   public void call() {
         someLongRunningSyncTask();
         return "finished"; 
   } 

    public void someLongRunningSyncTask() {

    }
}
```

Let's assume I want this method to delay any executions (and with this the rest webservice response) if already 5 other threads are running this method.

Are there any annotations or other abstract layers that already give me that behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

There is an interface `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` which could be implemented to intercept spring mvc requests. Spring also provides abstract implementation of it in `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` so you could just extend that and override whichever methods you require. From your description it looks like you would only need to override `preHandle` and `postHandle` methods. You could take a look at [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/) post for further example. Below is how you can achieve what you require any locking strategy that you find convenient;

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private final Semaphore semaphore;
    private final long waitTime;

    public CustomInterceptor() {
        // Hardcode this values or inject through spring as preferred.
        semaphore = new Semaphore(5);
        waitTime = 10;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        try {
            boolean acquired = semaphore.tryAcquire(1, waitTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (!acquired) {
                //TODO Do something with the response or keep waiting or whatever 
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Do something with this exception. Write custom message to response and then return false.
            // TODO write custom message to response i.e interrupted or something
            return false;
        }
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        semaphore.release();
        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }

}
```

Then instantiate in spring xml or java config and inject it to `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`'s interceptors property as below;

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/welcome">welcomeController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="customInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="customInterceptor" class="com.common.mvc.interceptors.CustomInterceptor" />
```

**PS:** Haven't tested to code but you should get the basic idea.